# Contas quantos ids iguais e fazer uma tabela do resultado maior para o menor

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um exercício que pedia:

Crie uma tabela `postagem` onde terá `id`, `titulo_postagem`, e crie também uma tabela chamada `comentarios` onde terá `id`, `id_postagem`, `comentario`.

Após as tabelas criadas pede-se que retorna as postagens com mais comentários.

Estava executando uma query da seguinte maneira, mas sem sucesso:

```
$selPostMaisComentados = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM postagem AS p INNER JOIN comentarios AS c ON c.id_postagem = p.id");
$selPostMaisComentados->execute();
```

Tabela `postagem`:

```
id   titulo
1    Poste aqui...
2    Etc...
3    fala mano
```

Tabela `comentarios`:

```
id id_postagem  comentario
1  1            oi
2  1            fala ae
3  2            iae
4  1            to inventando os comentario......
5  2            huhu
6  3            aiaiai
```

Comment: Você pode fazer um subselect

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um subselect para contar o numero de comentários por postagem e depois ordenar por ordem decrescente

```html
  SELECT p.id
        ,p.titulo_postagem
        ,a.total
    FROM postagem AS p 
    JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(c.*) total, c.id_postagem
             FROM comentarios AS c 
            WHERE c.id_postagem = p.id
            GROUP BY c.id_postagem
          ) a
    WHERE a.id_postagem = p.id
     ORDER BY a.total  DESC   ;
```

PS: Não testei o código

Comment: Fica dando seguinte erro: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: No caso seria p.id